# I am trying to run a sample Android application

Tags: android

I am trying to run this Android application

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/AccelerometerPlay/src/com/example/android/accelerometerplay/AccelerometerPlayActivity.html

but I get an error when I try to compile the source and run

```
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) // ERROR IN THIS LINE
```

And Eclipse is not giving me any bright suggestion either, except remove "@override"

Thanks a lot

Comment: what is the text of the error message?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your Java compiler settings are set to 1.5. Go to Project Properties | Java Compiler and change to 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Mostly you may need to import few packages.
First remove the @Override as suggested by eclipse, then you may see some useful suggestion.